# can we use the value of an input to define the width of other inputs or local variables in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Suppose we have an external processor gives our design the data width that we are allowed to work with.

for example the the data_width is the processor_data_bus[15:0] (processor_data_bus in 64 bits). Can we use this 16 bit value to configure other inputs or variables?

I asked chatGPT it gives me the following answer:

```
you can use a generate block to declare an input with a width based on the value of another input:



module my_module (
  input wire clk,
  input wire rst,
  input wire [7:0] data_in,
  output wire [7:0] data_out
);
  
  // Declare an input with a width based on data_in
  generate
    if (data_in >= 8) begin
      input wire [15:0] data_in_extended;
    end else begin
      input wire [7:0] data_in_extended;
    end
  endgenerate

  // Perform some operation using the inputs
  assign data_out = data_in_extended + data_in;

endmodule
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Module parameters.

Comment: @JonathanS. can we assign inputs to parameters? I mean `ocalparam [15:0] data_width = input_data_width;`

Comment: Just FYI, questions regarding ChatGPT responses are generally [off-topic](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9793/should-questions-about-chatgpt-responses-be-closed). I've however not added a VTC because if you remove the ChatGPT backstory the question is a reasonable one.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR;** No, you can't. ChatGPT is not a good teaching tool, it likes to make stuff up.

Data bus widths must be defined as constant expresions. Also `generate-if` and `generate-for` statements must use constant expressions.

---

Consider what it would mean from a circuit perspective. You would be requesting hardware (even if its in a simulation) to appear out of thin air when the value of the variable input changed.

One moment you would be operating on an 8-bit data bus. Now you change an input and suddenly you have a 16-bit data bus. Where would that extra circuitry come from?

It's akin to trying to make a PCB with a switch that suddenly make more traces appear when you flick it.

---

If however the width of the data bus is known at time of synthesis, then we have a completely different story. You are designing a module whose size depends on a fixed constant known when it is converted into hardware, but you want to be able to configure that constant value (at time of synthesis) for different designs.

This is what paramters are for.

```
module my_module #(
   parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8
)(
   input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_in,
   ...
);

...

endmodule


// Later when instantiated
wire [15:0] data_bus;
my_module #( .DATA_WIDTH(16) ) inst (
    .data_in(data_bus)
);
```

Here you can change the size of the bus when you instantiate the module. You can then use your generate blocks and paramters in your module to make a design that can be configured for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe everything ChatGPT tells you without trying it yourself. This code is illegal.

SystemVerilog is a *statically typed* language. That means you cannot change he type of variable/net after simulation starts, or after synthesis to hardware.

You can dynamically mask the data to a specific width.